# Django TypeError Using Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-settings

So Ive managed to screw something up between my production database settings for heroku.

Running the production settings locally I receive the error,

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

And I get the following error when deployed to Heroku seen here: http://tulsa-staging.herokuapp.com

```
Exception Value:    

cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

It appears that it has to do with my Database settings but I'm just not sure how to resolve this.

prod.py database settings for Heroku

```
urlparse.uses_netloc.append('postgres')
urlparse.uses_netloc.append('mysql')

try:
    if 'DATABASE_URL' in os.environ:
        url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])

        DATABASES = {
            'default':{
                'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
                'NAME': url.path[1:],
                'USER': url.username,
                'PASSWORD': url.password,
                'HOST': url.hostname,
                'PORT': url.port
            }
        }

except Exception:
    print 'Unexpected error:', sys.exc_info()
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using [dj-database-url](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url)?

It makes this so much easier:

```
import dj_database_url

DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
```

It automatically looks for and parses the value in `env['DATABASE_URL']`, falling back to what you pass into `default`.

It's what Heroku actually recommends you use.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example of `dj_database_url` configuration in settings.py? I couldn't find any of them in google search.

Comment: My answer is literally exactly that. It's all you need. After you install dj_database_url into your virtualenv, just paste that line into your settings.py, replacing your existing DATABASES set.

Comment: Thanks Jack. I use this line `DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='mysql://localhost')}` and it works absolutely fine. But where do I specify my mysql_database name, username and password? And what if I want to use different database settings for production and development version? This is not related to this question. But I got these doubts while trying the solution in my project. It will be great, if you could help me.

Comment: It's a basic netloc, so you just specify it like mysql://user:pass@localhost/database

Comment: For production, assuming you're on heroku, you don't need to do anything. dj_database_url will pick up the DATABASE_URL from heroku's env. For local stuff, I usually set that 'default' value equal to my local connection credentials.

Comment: Superb. It works like charm in my development server. For production I'm using [webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com). Will it be the same format there also?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with webfaction. There's no reason it shouldn't "work", but obviously the credentials may need to be different. I don't know if webfaction uses environment variables the same way heroku does.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25207/discussion-between-arulmr-and-jack-shedd)

Comment: Thanks you for your response . Using the settings you recommended I still receive the same error once I attempt to login.

Comment: Resolved my issue here. Didnt have any thing to do with the database settings. Discovered my secret_key was improperly set in the heroku environment.